# magic command %edit should invoke IDLE in iPython

Tags: python, ipython, python-idle

Is it possible to open IDLE instead of default vi in linux on executing %edit in iPython? 
How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracted from `%edit?`

```
%edit runs IPython's editor hook. The default version of this hook is
set to call the editor specified by your $EDITOR environment variable.
If this isn't found, it will default to vi under Linux/Unix and to
notepad under Windows. See the end of this docstring for how to change
the editor hook.

You can also set the value of this editor via the
``TerminalInteractiveShell.editor`` option in your configuration file.
This is useful if you wish to use a different editor from your typical
default with IPython (and for Windows users who typically don't set
environment variables).

....
```

So I guess you can set IDLE in $EDITOR or in .ipython/profile_xxx/[right configfile].py